# Limiting JavaScript Execution

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to prevent a script from executing outside of an element without using a frame or iframe? I am not talking about the CSP because it is all within the same domain. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="internal_application_frame">
             <div>
             </div>
             <script> /* internal domain script */
             </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to limit the script inside the "internal_application_frame" to see everything inside of it, however, it should not be able to access anything outside that div. So no access to the window object or anything. Is there a way to do that? If you need more clarification, I will try to word in differently. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: This is called *Sandboxing* btw

Comment: Do you mean DOM by everything?

Comment: Yes its possible, however its quite complicated and therefore not really worth it.

Comment: The internal application is prevented from is able to redirect the user to a different website. Part of a XSS idea for old browsers. I am an Information Technology student and my concentration is web security.

Comment: @JonasW. really? Do you have a PoC or a link to one?

Comment: this precise use case is exactly what iframes are for; why do you want to avoid using them?

Comment: You need to rewrite native api like window. to handle all calls from JS. Look to the Proxy object it can intercepts native calls (but it is quite slow) And this is really not simple task

Comment: @Vitalii yes the DOM but there are other things outside of the DOM, i.e. a virtual dom, shadow dom, and memory locations.

Comment: @CrayonViolent [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) and [JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter) are two possibilities that I'm aware of

Comment: @crayon loading the code as a string than wrapping it into an IIFE that overloads window etc.

Comment: @Hamms From the first look this takes code and execute it. But how it will help if code is alreay in HTML?

Comment: @Hmms all frames are deprecated and should not be used in the future. Frames also require you to change the doctype one that allows frames. I want to stay with html5 doctype because it is fairly future proof.

Comment: @Monarch shadow DOM? The browser support is a problem only i guess.

Comment: @Monarch `frame` and `frameset` have been deprecated, but not `iframe`

Comment: @entio the shadow DOM has nothing to do with the question. I was just using it as an example as things that exist outside the DOM.

Comment: @Monarch i didnt really read the question carefully (not mentioning the comments). Wanted to be helpful. Sorry!